# Exclude class from CSS property :not() doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make all links on the web page look in a specific way. However, it shouldn't apply to navbar links. I tried to exlude navbar using `a:not(.navbar)`, however, it didn't work: the style applies to all links, including `Link 1` in navbar:

**html**:

```
<body>
  <div class=".navbar">     
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>      
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>   
</body>
```

**css**:

```
body a:not(.navbar)  {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: black;       
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;   
}


body a:not(.navbar):hover  {
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #80b3ff;
    color: white;    
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgbEaG)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.navbar` class is applied to the container DIV of the navbar (not to the links), so your selectors need to be

```
div:not(.navbar) a { ... }
```

and

```
div:not(.navbar) a:hover
```

BUT you need a container `div` for the other links (without a class)  for this to work, which I inserted in my snippet below. And you had a little error in your class attribute in HTML: It's `class="navbar"` - without the dot.

```css
div:not(.navbar) a {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border-bottom: 6px solid red;
}

div:not(.navbar) a:hover {
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #80b3ff;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried to codepen it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReoPbg doesn't seem to work properly: only the first Link 1 is underlined, while it shouldn't have been changed at all.

Comment: I need only Link 2 and Link3 to be underlined. The css properties I wrote should only apply to Link 2 and Link 3. However, using the code your provided only Link 1 is underlined.